# Regex function in python having multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, data-extraction

I have a column of text data that I am converting to a string using ','.join() function. The data is given as shown below. I want to extract just the BP and its values from the converted string.

I know I have to use re.findall(). But I am not able to get the values as there are multiple conditions.

[image: The original data]

The code I have for now is given below.
[image: The output of the code I have for now]

So, I want to extract all the BP values and its corresponding values from the data.

As I am new to regex functions, any help with explanation is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So for the first line with `BP 98/60`, you want to just extract `BP 98` or as 2 entries with `BP 98` and `BP 60` ?   Do you mean you cannot extract those with 3 digits ?

Comment: I want ot extract the whole thing. BP 98/60.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to define your regex as follows:

```
regex = r'(BP \d+\/\d+)'
```

Assumptions:

1. the number after BP is from one digit up
2. the number after / is extracted as well

Let me know to fine-tune the regex if there is any additional criteria.

### Edit

Use the following regex if need to match the full text of BP (i.e match either BP or Blood Pressure):

```
regex = r'((?:BP|Blood Pressure) \d+\/\d+)'
```

We need parenthesis around the 2 optional texts.  `(?:` is used to make the group a non-capturing group so that you won't capture this segment of text in the `re.findall()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need the number after / as well. Ex: BP 98/60, BP 108/60, BP 125/75 should be the output.

Comment: Amended the regex as per your clarified requirement

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it better now.

Comment: Additional requirement: What if there is another data with 'Blood Pressure 96/120' and I want to extract that as well along with this? How do I add another condition in there?

Comment: You can just replace `BP` with `(?:BP)|(?:Blood Pressure)` in the regex above.

Comment: Ok, I see.  I amended my comment above

Comment: The whole regex will become `r'((?:BP)|(?:Blood Pressure) \d+\/\d+)'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229074/discussion-between-shiva-and-seabean).

Comment: Sorry, further amended and tested ok now.

Comment: Further added explanation of the use of `(?:` for your learning.